# Are there any Naming Conventions for Android SDK JARs?

Tags: android, jar, naming-conventions

Are there any Naming Conventions for Android SDK JARs ?

I haven't found the useful links.

Any links will be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no defined naming conventions for java libraries, normally library name is associated with simple letters, numbers and "-" character.